# How do I turn off my phone?

Tags: power-on, htc-wildfire-s

This might be a dumb question but found some links online which just look dangerous so I better ask.

I have a HTC Wildfire S. How can I turn it off? Is just removing the battery safe?

I want to shut down before I remove the batery. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try pressing and holding the Power button.  This should bring up a dialog box with several options, once of them being to turn off the phone.

Comment: Doh... Why didn't I think of that. It worked! I have 3 options: power off, restart and airplane mode. Thanks!